# Rollback write failure in S3 prefix-partition via Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

We are using Apache Spark(2.4.5) job via EMR, it reads a S3 prefix {bucket}/{prefix}/*.json, conducts some data massaging and then rewrites it back to the same {bucket}/{prefix} via the Spark job save() in overwrite mode. My question is, if the Spark job fails while it is re-writing the data to S3 prefix-partition, then is there any way we can restore data in that prefix-partition in any atomic/transactional way.
Does spark/EMR/S3 any/all of these support it?

Comment: You cannot use the same path to write the result. It will delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

Spark will write the new files to the folder because the cluster nodes are writing files at the same time and it is better to write the multiple files. So, when you did the overwrite action, Spark will remove the folder contents first and write the result.

The problem is that the Spark will not cache the whole original data, but just a part of the data that is needed in the code. If you write the result to the original path, then it will delete the original first and write the cached result into the folder.

You could use the append method but it will create some new files not just adding the data into the original files. Spark is not designed to do this and there is no way to revert when you overwrite or it fails.